# Google connector unable to authorize

Tags: magento, google-apps-script

I'm working on a what was supposed to be very small en quick project, but it is giving me hell. I'm working on a google connector to get data from Magento into Google Data Studio. Now I'm able to grab unprotected data, but as soon as i want to grab data behind an authorisation endpoint it just return nothing. I can't seem to figure it out.

```
var KEY_SIGNATURE = "Hidden.key";


function getAuthType() {
  return {
   type: 'KEY'
  };
}

function resetAuth() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.deleteProperty(KEY_SIGNATURE);
}

function isAuthValid() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var key = userProperties.getProperty(KEY_SIGNATURE);
  return validateKey(key);
}

function setCredentials(request) {
  var key = request.key;

  var validKey = validateKey(key);
  if (!validKey) {
    return {
    errorCode: 'INVALID_CREDENTIALS'
    };
  }
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty(KEY_SIGNATURE, key);
  return {
    errorCode: 'NONE'
  };
}

function validateKey(key) {
  if(key!=null && key !=undefined){
    return true;
  }
 return false;
}

function fetchData(request, startDate) {
try{
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties()

  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer token123"
  };

  var options = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers":headers
  };

  var url = 'www.mymagentowebsite.com/index.php/rest/V1/shipments?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=' + startDate + ' 00:00:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt';
  console.log(url);
  var data = [];
  console.log(JSON.stringify(options));
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  console.log('response');
  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  }catch(e){
    throw new Error("DS_USER: Unable to fetch your data: " + e);
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(parsedResponse)); <--This is not giving me any log with an authorized request
  return parsedResponse;
}

function getData(request) {
  var startDate = request.dateRange.startDate;

  // Prepare the schema for the fields requested.
  var dataSchema = [];
  var fixedSchema = getSchema().schema;
  request.fields.forEach(function(field) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fixedSchema.length; i++) {
      if (fixedSchema[i].name == field.name) {
        dataSchema.push(fixedSchema[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
  });

  // Prepare the tabular data.
  var response = [];
  var data = [];  
  data = fetchData(request, startDate);
  //do stuff with that data
  });

  return {
    schema: dataSchema,
    rows: response
  };
}
```

I can make the call just fine within postman, my url is correct, my token is correct. I just can't seem to get the data within this piece of code. It's the first time I'm using this so i got most of my code from tutorials. Am I doing the request wrong in any way? If the request is correct it would be weird because postman is able to retreive that data.

Comment: You might want to check what `response.getContentText()` is returning. You're now running the data through two JSON functions before checking what value is actually there.

Comment: Yeah i did that before as well, but it's not showing up in the logs.. console.log(response.getContentText()); returns nothing. But when i get the products which does not require authorisation, it works fine...

Comment: Yikes, it magically works now... i haven't changed anything that should give me my data now... I will find out how this happened and edit my post with the results if i can!